# Apply style to a TypeScript Node element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm currently learning TypeScript but I don't know how to solve this problem properly. I want to style a HTMLElement given as a argument to my styling function like this:

```
function styleElement(unstyled: HTMLElement) {
  const styled = unstyled.cloneNode(); // styleElement should be a pure function
  styled.style = { opacity: 0 }; // TypeScript says: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Node'.

  return styled;
}
```

I have checked the "Node" interface declaration and the style property is missing. As far as I know it is described in the W3C spec, that Node hasn't any style property. But how can I solve my problem with this limitation?

However overwriting the style property on a "HTMLElement" triggers a readonly error, which is strange too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast:

```
function styleElement(unstyled: HTMLElement) {
  const styled = unstyled.cloneNode() as HTMLElement;
  styled.style.opacity = 0 // Now works properly.
  // You can't reassign HTMLElement#style, that won't work.

  return styled;
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign a new object to `styled.style`. It won't work. `styled.style.opacity = "0"` is how it should be assigned.

Comment: Yes, I'm facing this error too. Do I have to assign each property of style in a individual assignment?

Comment: I know Object.assign but it doesn't help me, if I can't assign the result object to my style property. :/

Comment: @OleBläsing You don't have to assign the object back to `styled.style`. You can assign to `styled.style` itself `Object.assign(styled.style, {opacity: "0"})`